# Replace character only in certain string

Tags: regex, linux, bash, awk, sed

I need to replace every "_" with "-" in html file but only in  tag and only in "name" attribute.

So every this:

```
<a name="menu_portlet_test"> or <a name="whatever_is_here">
```

should become this:

```
<a name="menu-portlet-test"> and <a name="whatever-is-here">
```

Can't figure out how to force something like sed/awk to do it. Help!

Comment: HTML parsing using sed/awk, avoid, avoid, avoid.

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1820501).

Comment: @AvinashRaj: this '<dir badname="whatever_is_here">' also match

Comment: @walidtoumi try this `perl -pe 's/(?:<\S+\b[^<>]*? \bname="|(?<!^)\G)[^"_ ]*\K_/-/g' file`

Comment: where? http://regex101.com/r/dK5dX1/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed ':a
s/\(<[^>]* name="[^"]*\)_\([^"]*"\)/\1-\2/g;ta' YourFile
```

Should do most of you job. Not perfect due top html possibilities but should be 99,9% ok

**explaination**

`s//g`

- Search the pattern ( `<` followed by any non `>` ([^>]*`) followed by` name="`followed by (any non`"`(`[^"]*`) ) [ as group 1] followed by`*`[so first`*`between quote after name=]  followed by ( any non`"`(`[^"]*`) followed by`"`) [ as group 2 ]
- Replace it by content of group 1 followed by `-` followed by content of group 2
- `g` do it for any occurence on the line. This change 1 _ per name="" but on any name= of the line. `<... name="bla_bla_bla"> ... <... name="other_bla_bla"> ...` change to `<... name="bla-bla_bla"> ... <... name="other-bla_bla"> ...`

`ta`

- if a change occur in previous `s//`, redo the same action with modified content( in fact it is a if/goto to label `:a`)

Comment: seems to do the trick, thanks, now i'll have to figure out how it works :).
EDIT: Aaah! a loop, brilliant!

Comment: added some comment to explain

Answer (score 1):

Use a proper HTML handling tool, for example [xsh](http://p3rl.org/XML::XSH2), a wrapper around [Perl's XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML). The following commands can be saved in a script, or entered from its interactive environment:

```
open :F html file.html ;
for //@name set . xsh:subst(., '_', '-', 'g') ;
save :b ;
```

Comment: Looks interesting, so are these commands that you run from within an interactive shell? Perhaps some more detail in the answer would be useful.