# extracting particular rows from a html file based on the column value using sed or awk

Tags: regex, shell, unix, awk, sed

I have a html file in which a table has a number of rows.A **TR** tag may have its corresponding **/TR** in a another line .For example a.html file has the following.

```
<TABLE BORDER=1><TR><TH>col1</TH><TH>col2</TH><TH>col3</TH><TH>col4</TH></TR><TR><TD>aaa</TD><TD>bbb</TD><TD>ccc</TD><TD>ddd</TD></TR><TR><TD>eee</TD><TD>fff</TD><TD>ccc</TD><TD>mmm</TD></TR><TR><TD>jjj</TD><TD>kkk</TD><TD>lll</TD><TD>ssss</TD></TR>.........</TABLE>
```

Now i need to  extract the contents between tr and /tr tags(inclusive) into another html file based on the value of td that is found between the tr and /tr.

For example from the a.html file i need to create b.html which only has the rows in which third column value is "ccc",provided a.html remains the same.

```
<TR><TD>aaa</TD><TD>bbb</TD><TD>ccc</TD><TD>ddd</TD></TR><TR><TD>eee</TD><TD>fff</TD><TD>ccc</TD><TD>mmm</TD></TR>
```

i am newbie and have only a little idea abt sed and awk.
can anyone help me to get this done or suggest a better way so that it can be done easily.

Comment: You can't do this reliable with regex, imagine the next: `<tr>....<!-- </tr> --> ... </tr>` Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/632407).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First i added newlines after each <\tr>

```
 os.system("sed 's/<\/TR>/&\\\n/g' /tmp/file_full.html > /tmp/file_formated.html")
```

then executing the following line we get the result.This line checks for the column value to be "ccc" and if so it is wriiten into a seperate file.

```
os.system('sed -n "/<TD>ccc<\/TD>/p" /tmp/file_formated.html > /tmp/file_ccc.html')
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a proper parser. For example, [xsh](http://p3rl.org/XML::XSH2), a wrapper around Perl's [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML), which in turn is a wrapper around [Gnome libxml2 library](http://xmlsoft.org/):

```
open :F html file.html ;
ls //tr[td[3]='ccc'] ;
```

Comment: Yesterday, [you said it was a wrapper around  Perl's XML::XSH2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25763119/2088135) :)

Answer (score 1):

Use Python with BeautifulSoup to do this in a more structured and robust way: [Python BeautifulSoup scrape tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18966368/python-beautifulsoup-scrape-tables) - neither sed nor awk can actually parse HTML, and you may as well use something which can.

Here's a working program (Pandas uses BeautifulSoup inside, and it helps me fulfill  your desire to not have "for" loops):

```
import pandas
df = pandas.io.html.read_html('file.html')[0]
html = df[df[2] == 'ccc'].to_html()
print(html)
```

Comment: :iam trying to avoid using for loop in my python script for performance reasons and moreover i need to display this output file in the bowser using another php script .
so is that not possible by using  pattern matching by sed or awk commands?

Comment: Performance reasons?   You must be joking?  How big is your input?

Comment: This html file will be generated from a mysql table holding thousands of records.So i dont want to use a for loop.may be any other alternatives?

Comment: What does it even mean "I don't want to use a for loop."  Do you have a quantum computer handy?

Comment: @Nishanth: I have now added a working Python script which "does not use for loops."  I promise it will be fast.

Comment: @Nishanth you going to call external `sed/awk/pyhton/perl` process from your `php` and wondering about the loop-speed?! And about of the speed of the fork/exec?

Comment: Ahahaha. Thousands of records in a streaming operation is a performance problem?

Comment: @JohnZwinck I thought importing [`pandas`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant_panda) was illegal!!